Problem with javascript-regex matching, negative look-ahead inside a lookbehind
Given this string: ddd the ! key
and the Javascript regex: / !(?<=(?!the)\w+ !)/
I want to know the reason why the regex does NOT fail.
I expect the regex to fail matching, it doesn't, I don't know why.
i found an alternative that works, which is..
/ !(?<=\w+(?<!the) !)/
but i still prefer to make the one above work, because it's faster(maybe).

If you don't want the assertion to be true at a partial word match, you could also start with a word boundary.
So after matching a space and exclamation mark, assert that what is left to the current position is a word boundary not directly followed by a word starting with the
 !(?<=\b(?!the)\w+ !)

See a regex demo
If it should be the whole word the then you can add a word boundary after it
 !(?<=\b(?!the\b)\w+ !)


(?!the) matches at "he". You could update the regular expression to ensure there's a space before the word or it is the start of the string.
/ !(?<=( |^)(?!the)\w+ !)/

